# coldfusion 9 server crashing continously

Tags: coldfusion

Recently few days back my coldfusion server 9 started crashing, i checked various log and checked the logs inside the runtime/bin file and found the files named as  hs_err_pid11580.log

I am not sure what is causing this, any idea

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:149), pid=11580, tid=9912
#  guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter
#
# JRE version: 6.0_29-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.4-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000060f3800):  JavaThread "Thread-14" [_thread_in_native, id=9912, stack(0x0000000011120000,0x0000000011220000)]

Stack: [0x0000000011120000,0x0000000011220000]
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.load0(JJI)I+0
j  java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.load()Ljava/nio/MappedByteBuffer;+46
j  com.lowagie.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile.init(Ljava/nio/channels/FileChannel;Ljava/nio/channels/FileChannel$MapMode;)V+23
j  com.lowagie.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V+60
j  com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ZZ)V+294
j  com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V+6
j  com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.process([B)V+24
j  com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z[BZ)V+217
j  com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getAllFontNames(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[B)[Ljava/lang/Object;+54
j  com.lowagie.text.FontFactoryImp.register(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V+40
j  com.lowagie.text.FontFactoryImp.registerDirectory(Ljava/lang/String;)I+130
j  com.lowagie.text.FontFactoryImp.registerDirectories()I+6
j  com.lowagie.text.FontFactory.registerDirectories()I+3
j  coldfusion.document.DocumentServiceImpl.initializeDocumentService()V+9
j  coldfusion.document.DocumentServiceImpl.access$000(Lcoldfusion/document/DocumentServiceImpl;)V+1
j  coldfusion.document.DocumentServiceImpl$1.run()V+4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000000a8a4000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4016, stack(0x000000000d120000,0x000000000d220000)]
  0x000000000a8a3800 JavaThread "worker #4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13616, stack(0x0000000011970000,0x0000000011a70000)]
  0x000000000a8a2800 JavaThread "worker #3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11472, stack(0x0000000011870000,0x0000000011970000)]
  0x000000000a8a2000 JavaThread "worker #2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12272, stack(0x0000000011770000,0x0000000011870000)]
  0x000000000a8a1000 JavaThread "worker #1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13184, stack(0x0000000011670000,0x0000000011770000)]
  0x00000000060f5800 JavaThread "worker #0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5184, stack(0x0000000011570000,0x0000000011670000)]
  0x00000000060f5000 JavaThread "ServerThread" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9456, stack(0x0000000011470000,0x0000000011570000)]
  0x00000000060f4000 JavaThread "Thread-15" [_thread_blocked, id=2768, stack(0x0000000011220000,0x0000000011320000)]
=>0x00000000060f3800 JavaThread "Thread-14" [_thread_in_native, id=9912, stack(0x0000000011120000,0x0000000011220000)]
  0x00000000060f2800 JavaThread "scheduler-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3724, stack(0x0000000010f20000,0x0000000011020000)]
  0x00000000060f2000 JavaThread "Thread-13" [_thread_blocked, id=7500, stack(0x0000000010e20000,0x0000000010f20000)]
  0x00000000060f1000 JavaThread "Thread-12" [_thread_in_native, id=4812, stack(0x0000000010d20000,0x0000000010e20000)]
  0x00000000060f0800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-cfshopkart55" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9244, stack(0x0000000010820000,0x0000000010920000)]
  0x00000000060ef800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-cfguest" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9584, stack(0x0000000010720000,0x0000000010820000)]
  0x00000000060ef000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-contest" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8624, stack(0x0000000010620000,0x0000000010720000)]
  0x00000000060ee800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-cfcodeexplorer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11224, stack(0x0000000010520000,0x0000000010620000)]
  0x00000000060ed800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-classmates" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13228, stack(0x0000000010420000,0x0000000010520000)]
  0x00000000060ed000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-propublish" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11916, stack(0x0000000010320000,0x0000000010420000)]
  0x00000000060ec000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-realstateapp" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8072, stack(0x0000000010220000,0x0000000010320000)]
  0x00000000060eb800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-test123" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11884, stack(0x0000000010120000,0x0000000010220000)]
  0x00000000060ea800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-cfdocexamples" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3584, stack(0x0000000010020000,0x0000000010120000)]
  0x00000000060ea000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-errors" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8320, stack(0x000000000ff20000,0x0000000010020000)]
  0x00000000060e9000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-shopzone" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13252, stack(0x000000000fe20000,0x000000000ff20000)]
  0x00000000060e8800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-cfbookclub" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11840, stack(0x000000000fd20000,0x000000000fe20000)]
  0x00000000060e8000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-CFB" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8396, stack(0x000000000fc20000,0x000000000fd20000)]
  0x00000000060e7000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-checkData" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8652, stack(0x000000000fb20000,0x000000000fc20000)]
  0x00000000060e6800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-ExampleTable" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10444, stack(0x000000000fa20000,0x000000000fb20000)]
  0x0000000009c7f000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-insiderunning" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12908, stack(0x000000000f920000,0x000000000fa20000)]
  0x0000000009c7e000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-recipies" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12820, stack(0x000000000f820000,0x000000000f920000)]
  0x0000000009c7d800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-hairnewsnetwork" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14216, stack(0x000000000f720000,0x000000000f820000)]
  0x0000000009c7d000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-ecolife" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13376, stack(0x000000000f620000,0x000000000f720000)]
  0x0000000009c7c000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-cfm_videos" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8528, stack(0x000000000f520000,0x000000000f620000)]
  0x0000000009c7b800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-cfmarticles" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8124, stack(0x000000000f420000,0x000000000f520000)]
  0x0000000009c7a800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-reports" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7532, stack(0x000000000f320000,0x000000000f420000)]
  0x0000000009c7a000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-teachers" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9564, stack(0x000000000f220000,0x000000000f320000)]
  0x0000000009c79000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-gnf_dsn" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12896, stack(0x000000000f120000,0x000000000f220000)]
  0x0000000009c78800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-yellowpages" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5968, stack(0x000000000f020000,0x000000000f120000)]
  0x0000000009c77800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-cfartgallery" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11612, stack(0x000000000ef20000,0x000000000f020000)]
  0x0000000009c77000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-babynames" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9748, stack(0x000000000ee20000,0x000000000ef20000)]
  0x0000000009c76800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-realestatenz" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11276, stack(0x000000000ed20000,0x000000000ee20000)]
  0x0000000009c75800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-acetamritsar" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1192, stack(0x000000000ec20000,0x000000000ed20000)]
  0x0000000009c75000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-support" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8392, stack(0x000000000eb20000,0x000000000ec20000)]
  0x0000000009c74000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-chickendelight" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4620, stack(0x000000000ea20000,0x000000000eb20000)]
  0x0000000009c73800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-postcards_login" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12208, stack(0x000000000e920000,0x000000000ea20000)]
  0x0000000009c72800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-zimyellow" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10620, stack(0x000000000e820000,0x000000000e920000)]
  0x0000000009c72000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-cfpurchasepickup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14144, stack(0x000000000e720000,0x000000000e820000)]
  0x0000000009c71000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-i_mgr" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9116, stack(0x000000000e620000,0x000000000e720000)]
  0x0000000009c70800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-emailgenerator" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6388, stack(0x000000000e520000,0x000000000e620000)]
  0x0000000009c70000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-pronto" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8716, stack(0x000000000e420000,0x000000000e520000)]
  0x00000000062d5800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-randhawadesign" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12376, stack(0x000000000e320000,0x000000000e420000)]
  0x00000000062d5000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-photos" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6928, stack(0x000000000e220000,0x000000000e320000)]
  0x00000000062d4000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-worldofwaw" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12724, stack(0x000000000e120000,0x000000000e220000)]
  0x00000000062d3800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-contentMgr" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14264, stack(0x000000000e020000,0x000000000e120000)]
  0x00000000062d2800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-faqs" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11244, stack(0x000000000df20000,0x000000000e020000)]
  0x00000000062d2000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-cflinks" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4396, stack(0x000000000de20000,0x000000000df20000)]
  0x00000000062d1800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-gregdocument" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12716, stack(0x000000000dd20000,0x000000000de20000)]
  0x00000000062d0800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-ticksdb" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11496, stack(0x000000000dc20000,0x000000000dd20000)]
  0x00000000062d0000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-steadysoft" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10172, stack(0x000000000db20000,0x000000000dc20000)]
  0x00000000062cf000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-rfactorcentralsql" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2756, stack(0x000000000da20000,0x000000000db20000)]
  0x00000000062ce800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-AnswersClone" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11300, stack(0x000000000d920000,0x000000000da20000)]
  0x0000000006118000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-MagicListPro" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10980, stack(0x000000000d820000,0x000000000d920000)]
  0x0000000006117800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-girlrevolution" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7144, stack(0x000000000d720000,0x000000000d820000)]
  0x0000000006116800 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-sitelogging" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9332, stack(0x000000000d620000,0x000000000d720000)]
  0x0000000006116000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-quizone" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12884, stack(0x000000000d520000,0x000000000d620000)]
  0x0000000006115000 JavaThread "obj-skimmer-trades" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9384, stack(0x000000000d420000,0x000000000d520000)]
  0x0000000006114800 JavaThread "scheduler-0" [_thread_blocked, id=12744, stack(0x000000000d020000,0x000000000d120000)]
  0x000000000610e000 JavaThread "Thread-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6612, stack(0x000000000ca20000,0x000000000cb20000)]
  0x0000000006113800 JavaThread "Timer-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3956, stack(0x000000000d320000,0x000000000d420000)]
  0x0000000006113000 JavaThread "Timer-1" [_thread_blocked, id=13128, stack(0x000000000d220000,0x000000000d320000)]
  0x0000000006112000 JavaThread "Timer-0" [_thread_blocked, id=13972, stack(0x00000000079a0000,0x0000000007aa0000)]
  0x0000000006111800 JavaThread "scheduler-21" [_thread_blocked, id=12264, stack(0x000000000ce20000,0x000000000cf20000)]
  0x0000000006111000 JavaThread "jrpp-0" [_thread_in_native, id=11048, stack(0x000000000cd20000,0x000000000ce20000)]
  0x0000000006110000 JavaThread "scheduler-20" [_thread_blocked, id=13856, stack(0x000000000cc20000,0x000000000cd20000)]
  0x000000000610f800 JavaThread "mipc-1" [_thread_in_native, id=4572, stack(0x000000000cb20000,0x000000000cc20000)]
  0x000000000610e800 JavaThread "Thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=11956, stack(0x0000000007ba0000,0x0000000007ca0000)]
  0x000000000610d000 JavaThread "scheduler-19" [_thread_blocked, id=9124, stack(0x000000000c920000,0x000000000ca20000)]
  0x000000000610c800 JavaThread "scheduler-18" [_thread_blocked, id=8600, stack(0x000000000c820000,0x000000000c920000)]
  0x000000000610b800 JavaThread "scheduler-17" [_thread_blocked, id=5468, stack(0x000000000c720000,0x000000000c820000)]
  0x000000000610b000 JavaThread "scheduler-16" [_thread_blocked, id=12112, stack(0x000000000c620000,0x000000000c720000)]
  0x000000000610a800 JavaThread "scheduler-15" [_thread_blocked, id=4180, stack(0x000000000c520000,0x000000000c620000)]
  0x0000000006109800 JavaThread "scheduler-14" [_thread_blocked, id=13448, stack(0x000000000c420000,0x000000000c520000)]
  0x0000000006109000 JavaThread "scheduler-13" [_thread_blocked, id=11556, stack(0x000000000c320000,0x000000000c420000)]
  0x0000000005d5e800 JavaThread "scheduler-12" [_thread_blocked, id=4656, stack(0x000000000c220000,0x000000000c320000)]
  0x0000000005d5d800 JavaThread "scheduler-11" [_thread_blocked, id=10656, stack(0x000000000c120000,0x000000000c220000)]
  0x0000000005d5d000 JavaThread "scheduler-10" [_thread_blocked, id=6396, stack(0x000000000c020000,0x000000000c120000)]
  0x0000000005d5c000 JavaThread "scheduler-9" [_thread_blocked, id=12132, stack(0x000000000bf20000,0x000000000c020000)]
  0x0000000005d5b800 JavaThread "scheduler-8" [_thread_blocked, id=14184, stack(0x000000000be20000,0x000000000bf20000)]
  0x0000000005d5a800 JavaThread "scheduler-7" [_thread_blocked, id=13124, stack(0x000000000bd20000,0x000000000be20000)]
  0x0000000005d5a000 JavaThread "scheduler-6" [_thread_blocked, id=11064, stack(0x000000000bc20000,0x000000000bd20000)]
  0x0000000005d59800 JavaThread "scheduler-5" [_thread_blocked, id=11428, stack(0x000000000bb20000,0x000000000bc20000)]
  0x0000000005d58800 JavaThread "scheduler-4" [_thread_blocked, id=11504, stack(0x000000000ba20000,0x000000000bb20000)]
  0x0000000005d58000 JavaThread "scheduler-3" [_thread_blocked, id=13104, stack(0x000000000b920000,0x000000000ba20000)]
  0x0000000005d57000 JavaThread "scheduler-2" [_thread_blocked, id=8444, stack(0x000000000b820000,0x000000000b920000)]
  0x0000000005d56800 JavaThread "scheduler-1" [_thread_blocked, id=12752, stack(0x0000000009770000,0x0000000009870000)]
  0x0000000005d55800 JavaThread "scheduler-0" [_thread_blocked, id=14276, stack(0x0000000009670000,0x0000000009770000)]
  0x0000000005d55000 JavaThread "Transaction Domain PrivateJmsDomain" [_thread_blocked, id=12872, stack(0x0000000009570000,0x0000000009670000)]
  0x0000000005d54000 JavaThread "clock" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13008, stack(0x00000000084a0000,0x00000000085a0000)]
  0x0000000005d53800 JavaThread "Transaction Domain DefaultDomain" [_thread_blocked, id=11736, stack(0x00000000083a0000,0x00000000084a0000)]
  0x0000000005d53000 JavaThread "tyrex.util.daemonMaster" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11532, stack(0x00000000082a0000,0x00000000083a0000)]
  0x0000000005d52000 JavaThread "jndi-4" [_thread_blocked, id=10072, stack(0x00000000080a0000,0x00000000081a0000)]
  0x0000000005d51800 JavaThread "jndi-3" [_thread_blocked, id=9592, stack(0x0000000007fa0000,0x00000000080a0000)]
  0x0000000005d50800 JavaThread "jndi-2" [_thread_blocked, id=10400, stack(0x0000000007ea0000,0x0000000007fa0000)]
  0x0000000005d50000 JavaThread "jndi-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4700, stack(0x0000000007da0000,0x0000000007ea0000)]
  0x0000000005d4f000 JavaThread "jndi-0" [_thread_in_native, id=5452, stack(0x0000000007ca0000,0x0000000007da0000)]
  0x00000000060e5800 JavaThread "RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6684, stack(0x0000000007aa0000,0x0000000007ba0000)]
  0x0000000006108000 JavaThread "jms-fifo-5" [_thread_blocked, id=10392, stack(0x00000000078a0000,0x00000000079a0000)]
  0x0000000006107000 JavaThread "jms-fifo-4" [_thread_blocked, id=7796, stack(0x00000000077a0000,0x00000000078a0000)]
  0x0000000006413800 JavaThread "jms-fifo-3" [_thread_blocked, id=14224, stack(0x00000000076a0000,0x00000000077a0000)]
  0x0000000006106800 JavaThread "jms-fifo-2" [_thread_blocked, id=11520, stack(0x00000000075a0000,0x00000000076a0000)]
  0x0000000005d4a000 JavaThread "jms-fifo-1" [_thread_blocked, id=1492, stack(0x00000000074a0000,0x00000000075a0000)]
  0x000000000630d800 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13808, stack(0x00000000073a0000,0x00000000074a0000)]
  0x000000000624c000 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=13120, stack(0x00000000072a0000,0x00000000073a0000)]
  0x00000000061c5800 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12312, stack(0x00000000071a0000,0x00000000072a0000)]
  0x00000000046e8000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6540, stack(0x0000000005a90000,0x0000000005b90000)]
  0x00000000046d6800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13348, stack(0x0000000005990000,0x0000000005a90000)]
  0x00000000046cf800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8676, stack(0x0000000005890000,0x0000000005990000)]
  0x00000000046cf000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6224, stack(0x0000000005790000,0x0000000005890000)]
  0x00000000046ce000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13028, stack(0x0000000005690000,0x0000000005790000)]
  0x000000000467e000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12196, stack(0x00000000052c0000,0x00000000053c0000)]
  0x0000000004677800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11696, stack(0x00000000051c0000,0x00000000052c0000)]
  0x000000000054c800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=11940, stack(0x0000000000030000,0x0000000000130000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000000466c000 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000050c0000,0x00000000051c0000] [id=4728]
  0x00000000046f9000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000005b90000,0x0000000005c90000] [id=9056]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 12800K, used 914K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000f65d0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 9280K, 2% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f55a4a58,0x00000000f5e70000)
  from space 3520K, 18% used [0x00000000f6260000,0x00000000f6300000,0x00000000f65d0000)
  to   space 3776K, 0% used [0x00000000f5e70000,0x00000000f5e70000,0x00000000f6220000)
 PSOldGen        total 42368K, used 16637K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e2960000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 42368K, 39% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e103f6c0,0x00000000e2960000)
 PSPermGen       total 37952K, used 37778K [0x00000000d4000000, 0x00000000d6510000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 37952K, 99% used [0x00000000d4000000,0x00000000d64e4920,0x00000000d6510000)

Code Cache  [0x0000000000970000, 0x0000000000be0000, 0x0000000003970000)
 total_blobs=855 nmethods=420 adapters=388 free_code_cache=48492544 largest_free_block=24896

Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000140000000 - 0x0000000140013000     C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\bin\jrun.exe
0x0000000076ff0000 - 0x0000000077199000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076dd0000 - 0x0000000076eef000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefce90000 - 0x000007fefcefb000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007feff030000 - 0x000007feff10b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefee00000 - 0x000007fefee9f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefdae0000 - 0x000007fefdaff000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefecd0000 - 0x000007fefedfd000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x000000006fa30000 - 0x000000006fad3000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_08e61857a83bc251\MSVCR90.dll
0x000000006d890000 - 0x000000006e048000     C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x0000000076ef0000 - 0x0000000076fea000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefefc0000 - 0x000007feff027000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefd620000 - 0x000007fefd62e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefd860000 - 0x000007fefd929000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefae70000 - 0x000007fefaeab000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007fefebc0000 - 0x000007fefebee000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefd510000 - 0x000007fefd619000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000000006d800000 - 0x000000006d80e000     C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006d450000 - 0x000000006d477000     C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\bin\java.dll
0x000000006d850000 - 0x000000006d862000     C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefdba0000 - 0x000007fefe928000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.DLL
0x000007fefef40000 - 0x000007fefefb1000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefd200000 - 0x000007fefd403000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000000006d6a0000 - 0x000000006d6b7000     C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefd930000 - 0x000007fefd97d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007feff2f0000 - 0x000007feff2f8000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefc600000 - 0x000007fefc655000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefc5f0000 - 0x000007fefc5f7000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefbe60000 - 0x000007fefbe67000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fefc480000 - 0x000007fefc4db000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fef82e0000 - 0x000007fef830e000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x00000000771c0000 - 0x00000000771c7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000072cd0000 - 0x0000000072cf6000     C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x000007fefa720000 - 0x000007fefa747000     C:\Windows\system32\Iphlpapi.DLL
0x000007fefa710000 - 0x000007fefa71b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef3f70000 - 0x000007fef3f78000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fef9e10000 - 0x000007fef9e63000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x000000018000e000     C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\bin\portscan.dll
0x000007fefaeb0000 - 0x000007fefaec5000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fef8350000 - 0x000007fef8365000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fef8330000 - 0x000007fef8349000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x000007fef8320000 - 0x000007fef832b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fef8310000 - 0x000007fef8320000     C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll
0x000007fefc660000 - 0x000007fefc677000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefc360000 - 0x000007fefc3a7000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefcdd0000 - 0x000007fefcddf000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefcc60000 - 0x000007fefcc6f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000000006d740000 - 0x000000006d746000     C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\bin\rmi.dll
0x0000000006970000 - 0x000000000699a000     C:\ColdFusion9\lib\CFXNeo.dll
0x00000000045f0000 - 0x0000000004605000     C:\ColdFusion9\lib\cfregistry.DLL
0x0000000006bc0000 - 0x0000000006bd2000     C:\ColdFusion9\lib\PerfmonClient.dll
0x000000006d0a0000 - 0x000000006d263000     C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x000007fef8de0000 - 0x000007fef8e51000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x000007fef91f0000 - 0x000007fef9290000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_a4d6a923711520a9\COMCTL32.dll
0x000000006d6c0000 - 0x000000006d6cb000     C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x000007fefadb0000 - 0x000007fefadc8000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
0x000000006d340000 - 0x000000006d3a6000     C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx512m -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.rootDir=C:\ColdFusion9\runtime/../ -Djava.security.policy=C:\ColdFusion9\runtime/../lib/coldfusion.policy -Djava.security.auth.policy=C:\ColdFusion9\runtime/../lib/neo_jaas.policy -Dcoldfusion.classPath=C:\ColdFusion9\runtime/../lib/updates,C:\ColdFusion9\runtime/../lib,C:\ColdFusion9\runtime/../gateway/lib/,C:\ColdFusion9\runtime/../wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfform/jars,C:\ColdFusion9\runtime/../wwwroot/WEB-INF/flex/jars -Dcoldfusion.libPath=C:\ColdFusion9\runtime/../lib -Djmx.invoke.getters=true 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
PATH=C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\..\lib;C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\..\jintegra\bin;C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\..\jintegra\bin\international;C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\..\lib\oosdk\classes\win;C:\Python33\;C:\ImageMagick6-Q16;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ZipGenius 6\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssembli;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime Alternative\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;
USERNAME=AAAAAAAA-PC$
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 4066668k(843264k free), swap 8131476k(1314468k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.4-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_29-b11), built on Oct  3 2011 01:06:42 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 8.0 (VS2005)

time: Sat Sep 14 10:36:26 2013
elapsed time: 197 seconds
```

Comment: When you say "you checked the logs", what you posted above was the *only* relevant material? There was nothing in the exception.log, application.log, server.log or any of the JRun logs, eg: [instance name]-out.log or ~-event.log? How does this "crash" manifest itself? on-screen errors when requests are made? The server simply becomes unrepsonsive? It ties up all your CPU?

Comment: I am not clear, what you saying here, do i need to post the coldfusion out log files. also, well i am uninstalling cf9 now and reinstall again to see if problem persists or not, i will be back again once i see the server still creates issue or not.

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip` looks strange. You are running Java 6, possibly the version that was released with CF9. It might help to bump the JVM to used more than 512MB.

Answer (score 1):

An assertion in an exception handler failed, apparently deep within the JVM underlying coldfusion.  Either there is a bug in something running on the server, or there is some kind of hardware fault.

If patching doesn't fix it (updating both coldfusion and java), and you can't associate the error with a change to the application you are running on top of it which might be bringing this issue to light, you likely have bad RAM (or more rarely some other component has failed).

Comment: so what i need to do now. Change ram, is there any utility which finds out if there is any issue with jvm or system